Thanking the editor of one journal for their comments — on a paper that is being resubmitted to a different journal
I submitted a paper to a top economics journal and got desk-rejected.
The editor was nice enough to provide a personalized rejection letter with constructive comments which really help.
As I revise the paper and submit to somewhere else, should I include this editor's name in the acknowledgement?

It is not expected that you do so. I would personally be weary of acknowledging the editor because it implies that there was some formal/informal collaboration/discussion of results. Some may see this as you claiming some type of relationship with that editor. When in reality your interaction was purely within the context of that editor's job. If you are really intent on acknowledging that editor, I would email them and ask their permission to do so, at the very least that would imply some extra interaction beyond your desk reject email.

There's no downside, so you might as well do it. "We thank so-and-so for helpful comments" ought to be OK.

Indeed. No need at all to mention that they made their comments in their capacity for a different journal. It is enough that the person was helpful.

That would seem to depend on the nature of the advice. If it is advice on the content of the paper, then it might be important to do so. Even necessary.
But if it was advice on writing style or alternate journals and such, unrelate to the ideas in the paper, then it isn't likely to be as important.  But it wouldn't be inappropriate in any case.

There is no requirement to do so, but it is certainly something you can do.
It's fundamentally no different to thanking a "reviewer of an earlier version of this manuscript", or a co-worker who gave helpful comments. It's polite, and might be appreciated. But if you want to be especially careful, you could contact them to check if they were OK with it.
